# Windows10 - synaptics forgets settings

Tags: windows-10, synaptics-touchpad

i upgraded to windows 10 and updated synaptics drivers to 19.0.12.95 - so now drivers are compatible with windows 10, but it forgets settings in control panel. If i disable reverse two finger scrolling and system tray icon after restart icon is back and scrolling is reversed.

Any idea how to fix it?

I found out that settings in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics are missing after restart

What i tried:
set users permission to full control on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics

Answer (score 5):

Instead of reinstalling drivers you can simply modify a variable in regedit.

Change the value of `DeleteUserSettingOnUpgrade` to 0 from `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\Install`

After restarting your settings will be kept.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This fix still works on Windows 10 version 2004 and Synaptics driver version 19.5.10.75

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same problem. Fixed by re-installing the driver. I found the 19.0.12.95 driver on HP support website. Put 15-n207sa as computer model that will bring put the right driver.

Answer (score 1):

So i found out that drivers i downloaded had clickpad software, i downloaded some with touchpad software, drivers itself are probably same, but software is older synaptics one and it works and scrolls the way i like it :)

EDIT: i have used https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7 in internet explorer and downloaded latest synaptics drivers that had touchpad in name, also please check that you are downloading amd64 version for x64 systems.

Comment: For visitors with the same problem: do you have a link to those drivers?

Comment: i don't have the link, but i added what i did to get the drives

Comment: [Search](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/search.aspx?q=touchpad), HP specific [1](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=37410845-3ae1-4dbb-8e54-5c56a8955314) or [2](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=e9a2b577-9496-4258-a366-a076f348652e) and Generic [1](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=ddae5c8f-8636-4447-bd22-44f8b1e2d414) or [2](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=ad05aece-478d-4c0a-8147-c24dcd3a5a7c) all dated 15-7-2015